# How to send x-editable request to spring mvc backend?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, x-editable

I want to use x-editable into my page, and I learn it from [this document](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html).

The html element is here:

```
<a href="#" id="displayName" name="displayName" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="/candidates/updateDisplayName" data-title="Enter username" th:text="${displayName}">Click and input</a>
```

And my controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/candidates/updateDisplayName", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String updateDisplayName(@RequestParam(value = "displayName") String displayName, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Update display name");
    System.out.println(displayName);
    return "";
}
```

However, I got error again and again, the error message is like:

> {"timestamp":1417250586743,"status":400,"error":"Bad
>   Request","exception":"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException","message":"Required
>   String parameter 'displayName' is not
>   present","path":"/candidates/updateDisplayName"}

I knew that it's caused by the request parameter but not sure how to solve, could anyone help with this?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the "displayName" to "name" in the @RequestParam it works, thanks for chrome developer tools, it helps me.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/candidates/updateDisplayName", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String updateDisplayName(@RequestParam(value = "name") String displayName, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Update display name");
    System.out.println(displayName);
    return "";
}
```